# difference between add and set in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I need your help will you please tell me what difference between add() and set() in ArrayList. I Wrote a program uising set() and add() try to find out try to fing find out what are differences I search on the net but could not find my suitable answer

```
public class arraylistDemo 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(10);
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        al.add(null);


        al.set(0, 11);
        System.out.println("After Add "+""+al);

        al.add(1, "AA");
        System.out.println("Using add method"+ " " +al);

        al.set(1, "AA");
        System.out.println("Using set method"+ " " +al);
    }

}
```

O/P- Using add method [11, AA, B, null]
Using set method [11, AC, B, null]

Comment: Read the javadoc of `add` and `set`, they are pretty clear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is clearly stated in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: They are not working the same way. Read the link I posted.

Answer (score 10):

From `List`:

> add(E e)
>
> Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional operation).

---

> add(int index, E element)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).

---

> set(int index, E element)
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation).

---

Use a debugger and step one line at a time to see how your list changes. You will see that it does exactly what the Javadoc states.

Comment: Thanks buddy .. i got it . :)

Answer (score 8):

The add() method adds a value to the end of the list.
set() is used to replace an existing value in a specific index in the list.

Comment: yaa u r right but please check my code with output  both are working same way they replace the value